# How to plot this function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a simple function below (I omitted the allocations, etc. for brevity) that I have been tryig to plot against it's x value for specific values of N and T but I keep getting a dimensions error. I think that when I try to plot this I am defining an array for x and then plotting Psum(N', x, T') for certain N' and T' against these x, however MATLAB doesn't seem to like this. Can someone give me some direction please.

```
function U = Psum(N, X, T)
  for m = 1:N
    A(1,m) = (1/(m*pi))*sin(m*pi*X)*T*exp(-(m^2)*(pi^2)*T);
    % array terms of partial sum
  end
  M = -sum(A); % evaluate Nth partial sum
  U = T*(1-X) + M; % output U(X,T) = T(1-X) + V(X,T)
end
```

---

I'm getting a similar error when I try to plot the following, I think there must be something wrong with my general approach

```
 syms x;
 f = @(x)((x/(100*pi))*(exp(-(100^2)*(pi^2)*x)));
 x = 0:0.1:10000;
 plot(x,f(x),'r')
 title('PartialSum convergence');
 xlabel('T');
 ylabel('a_n');
```

the error I get here reads:

```
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
```

Comment: Can you explain which input values trigger errors? Before even attempting to plot `Psum`, did you verify that `Psum` gives correct results?

Comment: @EitanT. I don't really know what you mean, sorry. I have put numbers into Psum and it all turned out ok, I haven't got an error plugging in any individual values. However, when i write something like 'x = 1:100; y = Psum(100,x,100);  plot(x,y)' I get a dimensions error. I think there is something wrong with my general method, I am getting a similar error elsewhere too.

Comment: The result of the line `A(1,m) = (1/(m*pi))*sin(m*pi*X)*T*exp(-(m^2)*(pi^2)*T);` is a vector, because `sin(m*pi*X)` is a vector. Do you really mean that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the analysis of why you're getting a dimension mismatch error. From this line:

```
A(1,m) = (1/(m*pi))*sin(m*pi*X)*T*exp(-(m^2)*(pi^2)*T)
```

The element `A(1, m)` is supposed to be a scalar value in a two-dimensional matrix. Now let's see what are the dimensions of each of the multiplicands:

- `(1/(m*pi))` is a scalar (that is, a 1×1 matrix).
- `sin(m*pi*X)` has the same dimensions as `X`. Let's assume its dimensions are q×n.
- `exp(-(m^2)*(pi^2)*T)` has the same dimensions as `T`, and is multiplied by `T`.
  Therefore `T` must be a square matrix, so let's assume its dimensions are p×p.

What we get is a q×n matrix multiplied by a square p×p matrix, and the result must be a scalar (that is, 1×1 matrix). This forces q=1 and n=p.

Now let's look at this line:

```
U = T*(1-X) + M
```

We are forced to conclude that p=1, otherwise `T` cannot be multiplied by `X` from the right.

This means that your code forces `T` and `X` to be scalar! No wonder you're getting a error :)

The remedy is simple: revise the computation in `Psum` so that it can produce correct results for both a scalar `X` and a vector `X`. A possible fix would be adding another loop to iterate over all values of `X`:

```
function U = Psum(N, X, T)
    U = zeros(size(X));
    for k = 1:numel(X)  %// Iterate over all values of X
        for m = 1:N
            A(1,m) = (1/(m*pi))*sin(m*pi*X(k))*T*exp(-(m^2)*(pi^2)*T);
            %// array terms of partial sum
        end
        M = -sum(A); % evaluate Nth partial sum
        U(k) = T*(1-X(k)) + M; % output U(X,T) = T(1-X) + V(X,T)
    end
end
```

The output of this function has the same dimensions as `X`.

By the way, did you verify that `Psum` produces that correct result for scalar inputs?

Comment: Thank you, your code works and gives me what I am looking for. Why is it that sin(x) is a vector? How does MATLAB do the function plotting? Does it generate an array with each element the value of sin(x) at some x from x = 0:0.01:1, then match up the elements of the arrays as tuples (x(i),sin(x(i)) in the plane? So my problem was, that Psum could only handle scalar input and generate a scalar output, however, when I want to plot Psum I must input a vector array of x values, generate a corresponding vector array of Psum values and then ask MATLAB to plot the ...

Comment: ... elements of the two vectors as tuples defining points in the plane of the form (x(i), Psum(x(i))), where i denotes the natural enumeration of the elements of the array? (right?)

Comment: @user27182 If `x` is a vector, then `sin(x)` applies the sine function on each element of `x`, therefore the result is also a vector. To plot values, you can use MATLAB's [`plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) command, for example: `x = 1:100; y = Psum(100, x, 100); plot(x, y)`. You can also tell `plot` not to connect the points with lines, if you do not wish so.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what you are trying to accomplish, but just an observation for you: if your input X is a vector, line 3 can not be computed correctly

```
A(1,m) = (1/(m*pi))*sin(m*pi*X)*T*exp(-(m^2)*(pi^2)*T);
```

because the right hand side of the equation give you a vector, but the right hand side `A(1,m)` is one element, not vector. so you have dimension mismatch.
Hope this helps!